# User Account Block

Tags: users

I need to change the hyperlink of the "log in" tab in the user account block. The original hyperlink directs to (/drupal/user) and I want to change it to direct to some place else. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: ...you should tell us your Drupal version.

Comment: I'm using drupal 7